# Rails double nested form with active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, nested-forms

I have associations as follows:

variant has_may colours and colours has_many sizes. I am using active admin gem for managing backend activities. My models looks like,

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :variant_colours, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for : variant_colours, allow_destroy: true
end

class VariantColor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :variant

  has_many :variant_sizes, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :variant_sizes, allow_destroy: true
end

class VariantSize < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :variant_color
end
```

It is building variant_colours form with given fields but it is not building variant_sizes form under variant colours. Building meaning it does not populate fields on the form(UI)

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :product
      f.input :sku
      f.input :stock_quantity
      f.inputs do
        f.has_many :variant_colors, heading: 'Variant Colors',
                                allow_destroy: true,
                                new_record: true do |color_form|
          color_form.input :color
          color_form.input :sku_code
          color_form.input :stock
          color_form.inputs do
            color_form.has_many :variant_sizes, heading: 'Variant Sizes',
                                    allow_destroy: true,
                                    new_record: true do |size_form|
              size_form.input :size
              size_form.input :sku_code
              size_form.input :stock
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not need to wrap `f.has_many` with anything, so you could try removing one or both of the nested `f.inputs` and `color_form.inputs` that you have wrapping your `has_many` input blocks in the form.

My next thought would be, how are you declaring the permitted params in your controller? They probably need to be something along the lines of:

```rb
permit_params :name, :product, :sku, :stock_quantity, 
  variant_colors_attributes: [
    :color, :sku_code, :stock, :_destroy, 
    # I don't think I've ever tried to double nest in this way, you may need diff syntax
    variant_sizes_attributes: [:size, :sku_code, :stock, :_destroy]
  ]
```

My guess is the issue is in your permitted params.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain it properly. Actually it's not populating the fields on form itself.

Comment: Have you tried removing or commenting out the `color_form.inputs do` wrapper you're nesting those inputs in? Also, shouldn't VariantSize belong to Variant (not VariantColor)? I cannot think of a reason why a color object should have a size associated with it. TBH because the attributes are the same on both models, I'm wondering why they aren't different subtypes of a single superclass using STI.

Comment: For the models you have now, you likely also need to add something like `has_many :variant_sizes, through: :variant_colours` to Variant and `has_one :variant, through: :variant_color` as well

Comment: Worked after commenting out color_form.inputs do Thank you for your help @Allison